# Übel Blatt Manga: What was the purposes of naming the 4 lances of betrayal?

Tags: ubel-blatt

**Potential Spoilers**

What was the purpose of the seven heroes to name the 4 people as betrayers of their quest, even though

> They were the real heroes and completed it. I understand why they were killed. Why not just let the king know that they too died after completing the quest? Why was their name dragged through mud. We see a lot of negative consequences of this, for example Kfeer's family ostracized and his territory thrown in Civil War.

Why demean the memory of their friends instead of honoring their memories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every hero is praised and loved by people. But it's hard to have many heroes. Don't you think, that if there were 9 heroes, 4 dead of them would actually get even more attention and praise, than rest 5 survivors, since dead ones would be considered as martyrs?

I suppose, 5 betrayers named killed heroes as lances of betrayal, to get as much fame and praise as possible

**I'm updating my answer after rereading several tomes.**

In 5th tome, 6th chapter, when Glenn confesses to Ms. Gleaa, that 4 lances were not traitors at all, she asks him same question, as you did here. What Glenn answers:

> We were young... Too blind and too consumed with ourselves to consider other options...

Answer (score 0):

My memories of Ubel Blatt are very foggy (sadly).

I am certain it was to further increase their personal status and profits.
Not only did they fulfill the hardest of quests, they even saved the kingdom from the traitors.

And obviously they didn't think of the 4 as friends.

(If I find the time I will reread it :)